# Need to automatically install service after compiling

Tags: vb.net

I have a service that runs on a server. I have been tasked with installing and starting the service automatically after compiling. I have been able to automatically start the service after INSTALL, but I have to automate the install as well. And just as a means of looking anticipating the next request, I need to detect if a service is running and if it is, stop it and uninstall it.

Open to suggestions.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnAfterInstall(savedState As IDictionary)
    MyBase.OnAfterInstall(savedState)

    'The following code starts the services after it is installed.
    Using serviceController As New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController(WriteService.ServiceName)
        serviceController.Start()

    End Using
End Sub
```

This works great AFTER the manual install.

Comment: Actually this one is a dead stick, the powers that be decided that having it start after install was good enough, however they now want to start and stop with a bat file so they can set a task to do it. So now I will post my bat question! LOL!

Comment: Yep! I went through all answers and got what I needed. So no post forthcoming! :)